# Azure Functions vs lambda for scheduled jobs

Tags: azure-functions

We're developing some simple serverless things, and we're testing both Azure Functions and aws lambda. The one I'm working on right now will be executed every 5 minutes around the clock. Using the aws lambda calculator I'm looking at around $0.39 per month for this single function.

Azure Functions need to be "continuously running" to be able to run on a schedule like this (from what I understand), and in order to do that the underlying app service needs to be in the "Basic" tier, which brings the price up to minimum $55.80 per month. I realize that by using the same "Function App" for multiple functions that would bring the individual function price down, but in my case it would take something like 141 similar function apps to bring down the price in line with the aws offering.

So my question: Is this correct? Is "Always on" the only way for an azure function to run on schedule? (I realize there's a multitude of ways to trigger it externally but we're trying to keep the complexity down and not have too many moving parts).

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions does support "continuously running" if you use the **Consumption Plan**. In that plan, you can easily set up a timer to run every 5 minutes, without needing to configure "Always on". The billing will also be similar to Lambda as described below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview#pricing

> Azure Functions has two kinds of pricing plans, choose the one that
>   best fits your needs:
>
> **Consumption plan** - When your function runs, Azure provides all of the
>   necessary computational resources. You don't have to worry about
>   resource management, and you only pay for the time that your code
>   runs.
>
> **App Service plan** - Run your functions just like your web,
>   mobile, and API apps. When you are already using App Service for your
>   other applications, you can run your functions on the same plan at no
>   additional cost.

Pricing details are here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/